# Alternative way to create ports in JointJs

Tags: jointjs

I have come across this page about creating ports in JoinsJS and it fits my needs:
https://resources.jointjs.com/tutorials/joint/tutorials/ports.html

However, it seems that this way got deprecated and the documentation offers no alternative solution. How can I achieve the same functionality in the new way?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it is deprecated,

you can see in their latest documentation https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v3.4/joint.html#shapes.devs

that it's not tagged as "deprecated" or "for backwards compatibility".

Comment: That's weird, they say so at the top of the link I posted. I am not sure when it was written though.

Comment: You're right, it's not very clear. A date in their page may be useful..

I've just found that your page comes from the "Tutorial" section (and not "JointJS" section), left menu "Archive" : https://resources.jointjs.com/tutorial/ports
 
 
So it's in an "Archive" section of their website, but not officially deprecated...
Furthermore, their page https://resources.jointjs.com/tutorials/joint/tutorials/ports.html use the latest version 3.4.4...